# Javascript onblur & onclick function saves record multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one Javascript function named "`saveForm()`" from which I am saving the records in the database.

My form has one button as 'Save in draft' which saves the record in draft mode. On this button, there is `onclick` event which calls above javascript "`saveForm()`" function.

Now, I have a feature about autosave the record which calls javascript above "`saveForm()`" function on every `onblur` event of the form field.

Now, the scenario is when I fill one of the fields & directly clicks on 'Save in draft' button, it saves the records multiple times as both(`onblur` & `onclick`) events called parallel.

**Onclick :**

```
<input type="button" class="btn" id="draftsave" value="Save in draft" onclick="javascript: saveForm(this.form.id, 'draft');" />
```

**Onblur :**

```
jQuery(document).delegate(":input[type!='button']", "blur", function() {            
    saveForm(this.form.id, "draft");
});
```

[HTML Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdSK7.png)

Comment: Why not just leave the blur handler and remove the click one? The only case where that wouldn't trigger is if someone directly clicks the button without ever focusing one of the inputs, so you could also manually focus the first input, using the `autofocus` attribute.

Comment: When every field has the save functionality on blur, why do you want to do it on click of the button as well?

Comment: As a side note, `.delegate` is deprecated and has been for a while, you should switch to `.on` and swap the first two arguments.

Comment: you could split up the logic, so you have something in the database called "draft" or something like that which holds the autosave values. Then when *saveForm()* is called, you can delete the draft and go on to your form data logic.

Comment: @VinodBhavnani : actually I have the big form which has more than 30 fields, so we are doing autosave in the background on every onblur event without any knowledge to end user. User will only have information about save as draft button & final submit button

Comment: But then you can just intimate the user onclick of the button. Remove the save functionality from the button onclick

Comment: it's requirement & I can't do this.. Sorry :(

Comment: You could also add a status field in your table containing the form data to see if it's a filled out form, or whether it's a draft. So basically every time the onblur function is called, it's a draft, and every time the *saveForm* function is called via the button, it's a finished form for submit.

Comment: Guys basically there are a lot of ways to do this, but I think it's redundant. I understand it's a requirement, but requirements have to be argued upon if they are wrong. Designers and BAs do not know the technicalities, they need to be told.

Comment: I do not understand what is the problem if the form get saved multiple times. This is what the feature wanted, right? or maybe you do not want to launch a auto save immediately after onblur, you can start a time to delay it and kill it when the button is clicked very quick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below or you can check before inserting in database but in that case it will make multiple backend calls, its better to keep a check in front end while making the backend call, so you can try the below code and see if it solves your problem:

```js
var clicked;
$("#draftsave").click(function() {
  clicked = true;
});

jQuery(document).delegate(":input[type!='button']", "blur", function() {
  if (!clicked) {
    saveForm(this.form.id, "draft");
  } else {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

okay so if you want this functionality(but you can just keep yout submit associated to onChange) just send a boolean filed on change event like

```
<input type="text" onChange="someFunction(true);">
```

Now you can take a global boolean variable and update its value with the value of onChange boolean param.

```
boolean isOnChangeCalled=false;//global variable

function someFunction(isOnchange)
{
this.isOnChangeCalled=isOnchange
}
```

and in case of onClick just check if this boolean ie isOnChangeCalled is set to true only then perform a onClick event otherwise prompt user that form is already saved

**To verify in back end**
In case data is already submitted and user clicks submit button then then just check if the data is already updated in database by comparing two objects but that is an extra overhead and return appropriate reponse in case data is already there

**UPDTATE**
you can maintain a clone of your form object and before your onClick event you can compare both objects and if they are same just prompt user the relevant message